# Division with two decimal places not working

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to divide 193251715/659669075 and get the result of 29.30% (so to round it up to the nearest value with two decimal points)

Here's what I've done:

```
new BigDecimal(193251715).divide(new BigDecimal(659669075) , 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).multiply(new BigDecimal(100))
```

But I'm getting 29.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are multiplying by 100 to show a percentage. You should divide with a scale of **4** instead of 2, then set the scale to 2:

```
new BigDecimal(193251715).divide(new BigDecimal(659669075), 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                         .multiply(new BigDecimal(100))
                         .setScale(2)
```

Comment: Or just start with `100`: `new BigDecimal(100).multiply(new BigDecimal(193251715)).divide(new BigDecimal(659669075) , 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`.

Answer (score 2):

set `scale of 4`, to include more decimal spaces.

Set scale of 2 lastly, to make it 29.30 instead of 29.30000.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal(193251715)
                .divide(new BigDecimal(659669075), 4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                .multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).setScale(2);
        System.out.println(bg);
    }
```